# Reference Type Equality at compile time

Tags: java, reference

I came across following statement in Java Language Specification-8.It states that 2 classes are same at compile time if:

1. They have same binary name(Canonical Name for outer classes).
2. Their type arguments are same (if any).

[Java Spec Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.4)

But why does compiler raises a duplicate class error for

```
class Test<String>{
    ...
}

class Test<Integer>{
    ...
}
```

Here binary name is same but argument types are different.What am I missing here?

Comment: That's the same class name with a different arbitrary name for their generic type parameter. The `String` and `Integer` there are your own confusingly chosen identifiers; they are not `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Integer`. Whatever you were trying to do, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: If I change Test<String> to Test<T extends String> and Test<Integer> to Test<T extends Integer>?

Comment: isn't that documentation about **reference types**? it is not stating that 2 **classes** are the same, but 2 **reference types** like the type of `myList` in  `private List<String> myList`. Sure not the same as in `private List<Integer> myList` (`private` added for clarification only, so it's clear that this is defining a field, same true for local variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the argument, but the [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) of a generic class. This type information is removed at runtime, so from a JVM point of view it is identical.

You can read more about `Generics` and `Type Erasure` in the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What are type arguments for classes?

Comment: It allows to be agnostic to certain types, if types don't matter to the implementation, i.e. `List`s don't care which kind of object they carry. I added a link to the `Generic Type` description above.